# vmtools fail to install shareable folders as no gcc binaries are found

Tags: xubuntu, gcc, vmware-player

I tried to set up a x64 18.04.2 xubuntu on a windows 10 pro host machine using the VM Player 7. 
Installing xubuntu works fine. The Vmtools however are not able to set up the shareable folders between the host and the guest machine. This is how I tried it:

VM Player >  Manage > Install VMWare tools. After extraction I ran the sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d command in the folder's terminal. I put the Log messages down below. As the logs are very long I only put in the error messages.

I tried to sudo apt-get install gcc-8 as suggested in another thread on this topic. Is there anyone that can help me get this running?
I also tried sudo apt-get install gcc.
And yes I did sudo apt update as well.
I'm very new to linux systems so don't hesitate pointing out the obvious.

Thank you guys very much.

Logs:

```
The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the host OS 
and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish 
to enable this feature? [yes] 


(process:9380): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:19:16.043: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed

(process:9406): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:19:16.276: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed

(process:9417): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:19:16.507: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed

WARNING: This program cannot compile any modules for the following reason(s)...

- This program could not find a valid path to the gcc binary.  Please ensure 
that the gcc binary is installed on this sytem.

[ Press Enter key to continue ]
```

Comment: Do the tools need gcc-8 specifically? if not, the easiest way is likely to install the default `gcc` package for your system - which will install `gcc-7` **and** symlink it to `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: @steeldriver I do not need gcc-8 specifically. I'm very new to linux, how do I symlink?

Comment: If you do **not** need gcc-8 specifically, then you don't need to worry about doing the symlink yourself - just install the `gcc` package (or the `build-essential` metapackage) and `apt` will take care of everything for you

Comment: @steeldriver: This is what I thought, I did it via sudo apt-get install gcc, however this leads to "gcc is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2)." in the terminal and not changing the error message when trying to install the vmtools. (Edit: Accidential Sent)

Comment: Sorry I missed that you already tried that - so does `/usr/bin/gcc` exist? what is the output of `type -a gcc`? what happens if you type `gcc --version`?

Comment: no usr/bin/gcc does not exist, should it? gcc --version leads to "gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0"

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc` (note the leading `/`) should exist - the fact that `gcc --version` works suggest it does (unless you manually installed gcc-7.4.0 somewhere else on your `PATH`). The problem with `vmware-install.pl` must be due to something else - possibly a mismatch between the version of gcc installed on the system and that used to compile the kernel

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to @steeldriver for the help provided. What solved the problem for me is to go back on an earlier release of xubuntu. In my case 1404 solved it (I didnt try out any other xubuntu versions in between, so maybe those work as well. I still have the 1804 machine running if someone comes up with an other idea.

Cheers